# How to group and sum some results in others ( Style format in Euros)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I want to make a pie chart over Europe and some specific countries, i need to groupe and sum some countries or companies in a group call "Others", for example: all the companies that have the budget less than 10000 euros.

```
import pandas as     pd
from   pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy  as     np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    Year    Project Entity  Participation   Country Budget
0   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   FUNDACION IMDEA NETWORK*    Participant Spain   € 304,000
1   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   ROHDE & SCHWARZ GMBH*   Participant Germany € 120,000
2   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS (UK) LIMITED    Coordinator UnitedKingdom   € 797,500
3   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   HUAWEI TECHNOLOGIES DUESSELDORF GMBH    Participant Germany € 648,000
4   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   TELEFONICA INVESTIGACION Y DESARROLLO SA*   Participant Spain   € 531,976
5   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   CHALMERS TEKNISKA HOGSKOLA AB*  Participant Sweden  € 233,000

datos1 = (df[(df['Project'].str.contains('5G-MOBIX')) & (df.Country.str.count('Spain'))])
datos2 = 'La cantidad de proyectos es ='
datos4= 'El presupuesto total en Euros es ='
print(df[(df['Project'].str.contains('5G-MOBIX')) & (df.Country.str.count('Spain'))& (df['Country'].replace(!=''NOKIA SPAIN SA'','Other')]) 
print(datos2, datos1.Country.str.count('Spain').sum())
print(datos4, datos1.Budget.sum())
```

I have an error with the command "replace".

```
datos1 = (df[(df['Project'].str.contains('5G-MOBIX')) & (df.Country.str.count('Spain'))])
datos2 = 'La cantidad de proyectos es ='
datos4= 'El presupuesto total en Euros es ='
print(df[(df['Project'].str.contains('5G-MOBIX')) & (df.Country.str.count('Spain'))& (df['Country'].replace(!=''NOKIA SPAIN SA'','Other')]) 
print(datos2, datos1.Country.str.count('Spain').sum())
print(datos4, datos1.Budget.sum())

explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0)
datos1.groupby("Entity")["Budget"].sum().plot(kind="pie", explode=explode, counterclock=False, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90, figsize=(10, 8))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("SPAIN in the project 5G-MOBIX", bbox={"facecolor":"0.5", "pad":5}, color='b')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.show()
```

i expect this result in the pie chart:

```
     Year       Project     Entity  Country   Budget                                                                             
742  2018   825496 - 5G-MM  'NOK'   Spain     € 556815.21                                                                       
743  2018   825496 - 5G-MM  'TDE'   Spain     € 747879.88                                                              
778  2018   825496 - 5G-MM  'ALS'   Spain     € 152868.86                                                                        
780  2018   825496 - 5G-MM  'OTHER' Spain     € 300000
```

Comment: *I have an error with the command "replace"* please include the full text of your error in your question. You can edit the question, don't post it as a comment.

Comment: `!=''NOKIA SPAIN SA''` this is not valid python syntax. Are you tryuing to find everything that is not `'NOKIA SPAIN SA'`? If so, take a look at the regex examples in the [`replace` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: i tried to create a filter to obtain something like this:
      Year Project                       Entity                        Country     Budget                                                                             
742  2018   825496 - 5G-MM  'NOKIA SPAIN SA'   Spain      556815.21                                                                       
780  2018   825496 - 5G-MM  'OTHER'                   Spain      450000