# Pandas python + format for values

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, pandas-groupby

This is the code:

```
import pandas as     pd
from   pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy  as     np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.head(3).style.format({'Budget': "€ {:,.0f}"})
Year    Project Entity  Participation   Country Budget
0   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   FUNDACION IMDEA NETWORK*    Participant Spain   € 384,000
1   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   ROHDE & SCHWARZ GMBH*   Participant Germany € 12,000
2   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS (UK) LIMITED    Coordinator UnitedKingdom   € 997,500

datos1 = (df[(df['Participation'].str.contains('Coordinator')) & (df.Country.str.count('Spain'))])
datos2 = 'Las participaciones en proyectos como coordinador son='
datos4= 'El presupuesto en Euros es ='
display(datos1)
print(datos2, datos1.Country.str.count('Spain').sum())
print(datos4, datos1.Budget.sum())

Year    Project                           Entity                  Participation Country Budget
2015    671598 - 5G-CROSSHAUL   UNIVERSIDAD CARLOS III DE MADRID*   Coordinator Spain   899471.88
2015    671517 - SONATA - 5G    ATOS SPAIN SA*                      Coordinator Spain   602437.50
2015    671704 - CHARISMA - 5G  FUNDACIO PRIVADA I2CAT *FI2CAT      Coordinator Spain   557312.50
```

I want to have the same result with the budget in euros, i tried with this code:

```
display(datos4, datos1.Budget.sum().style.format('€ {0:,.0f}'))
```

Update:

```
display(datos4, datos1.Budget.sum().style.format('€ {0:,.0f}'))
```

This line was solve with this code:

```
print(datos4, '€ {0:,.0f}'.format(datos1.Budget.sum()))
```

Now, i only have problems with the style format in the budget, i tried like
to fix with this code:

```
datos1 = (df[(df['Participation'].str.contains('Coordinator')) 
             & (df.Country.str.contains('Greece')) 
             & (df.Budget.apply('€ {0:,.0f}'.format))])
```

or

```
df['Budget']=df.Budget.apply('€ {0:,.0f}'.format)
datos1 = (df[(df['Participation'].str.contains('Coordinator')) 
                 & (df.Country.str.contains('Greece'))])
```

i have errors with the code, please any idea?

Comment: Hi Diego, it's helpful if you can include code that others can run that demonstrates your problem. For example, if you create a sample dataframe in the code that replicates an example of what you have, so that we can run into the same error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i updated the code, please if you have any idea overall for the table in euros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you not to mix logic with appearance. Create the table according to logic, and then format it. Try this code:

```
datos1= df.loc[ \
                   df.Participation.  \
                   str.contains('Coordinator',case=False) \
                  & df.Country. \
                    str.contains('Greece',case=False) ]

datos1_pretty= datos1.style.format({"Budget":'€ {0:,.0f}'})
```

You can specify more columns in the dict.

Comment: Thanks, the code that you wrote solve the problem @Kantal

Comment: Thanks for everything, i invited you to check this problem, maybe it's simple for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688183/how-to-group-and-sum-some-results-in-others-style-format-in-euros

Answer (score 0):

`datos1.Budget.sum()` is the sum of a series, which returns a `float`, so you can't apply Pandas `style.format` to it. Try this:

```py
'€ {0:,.0f}'.format(datos1.Budget.sum())
```

For the table: `df['Budget'] = df.Budget.apply('€ {0:,.0f}'.format)`, if you want to have formatted strings in the `Budget` column. `style.format` only works when you have an html frontend, i.e. jupyter.

Comment: Thanks, that's solve the last part, but in the table how can i show the budget in euros?

Comment: i updated the code and i use Jupyter, i tried 
df['Budget']=df.Budget.apply('€ {0:,.0f}'.format)   inside of the table filter and before, but i doesn't run.

Comment: what does "it doesn't run" mean?

Comment: the code has errors, please check the update in the question.

Comment: Thanks @mcsoini for all the help that you brought me helps to solve the problem.